# Flutter Navigation: how to make a routename as a funciton of an instance?

Tags: flutter, navigation, instance

I want to make a new page which depends on a text input that a user typed in, so I want to make a routeName as a function of an instance, the following code doesn't work..

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: 'main',
  routes: {
    'main': (context) => MainPage(),
    NodeInsideChat().routeName(): (context) => NodeInsideChat(),

  },
);
}
}
```

Here You can see I'm trying to make routeName be newly genereated as an each page is created. But I have no idea what to pass inside NodeInsideChat()..

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
 }

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
String wordInput;

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
      onChanged: (value) {
        wordInput = value;
      },
    ),
    RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, NodeInsideChat(wordInput).routeName(),
            arguments: NodeInsideScreenArguments(wordInput));
      },
      fillColor: Colors.red,
      child: Text('Go to the new Page'),
    ),
  ],
);
}
}

 class NodeInsideChat extends StatelessWidget {
  NodeInsideChat(this.wordInput);

  final String wordInput;

  String routeName() {
   return wordInput;
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final NodeInsideScreenArguments args =
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

   return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF8A80),
    title: Text(
      args.wordindex,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

class NodeInsideScreenArguments {
 final String wordindex;
 NodeInsideScreenArguments(this.wordindex);
 }
```

By ModalRoute or onGenerateRoute, I could not set the routeName as a function..

Comment: i am not sure what you really want to achieve, whats your goal actually? you want to pass some dynamic content to a new route or waht?

Comment: I want to create a new chat room based on a newly typed text. So I need to make a routename as a function of a text input.

Comment: why cannot you use a normal / static route name (like  `'newChatRoom'` for example)? and pass some specific param to route  `Widget`?

Comment: But with ModalRoute or onGenerateRoute, I can only pass arguments inside the Widget build(BuildContext context), not to the routename above it.

Comment: Because I want a new room to be made everytime a new text input comes

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: Yes I tried them,, but can two different rooms be distinguished by the same static routename?

Comment: as i said pass specific parameters when using [Navigator.pushNamed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html) - it has optional `{Object arguments}` where you can pass room id / persom id / whatever... - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#4-navigate-to-the-widget

Comment: Yes I definitely need to try it.. Thanks